# DAX expression for average max value per variable

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table called *filtered_POR050* with multiple columns containing parcel delivery information (postal code, hour, day, tour id) from which I am able to create the following matrix:
[image: matrix]

`From what you can see:`

1. *GroupeCP* is a column with postal codes
2. 520, 521, 522.. is a column with route id called *ID TOURNEE*
3. *lundi 11 septembre 2023..* is a column with delivery date called *JOUR LIV*
4. Max_Heure LIV is a measure that calculates the latest delivery hour from column *Label_HEURE LIV*
5. Min_Heure LIV is a measure that calculates the earliest delivery hour from column *Label_HEURE LIV*

`Here are my formulas:`

```
Max_Heure LIV = CALCULATE(MAX('filtered_POR050'[Label_HEURE LIV]))

Min_Heure LIV = CALCULATE(MIN('filtered_POR050'[Label_HEURE LIV]))
```

`My matrix is built as follows:`

[image: construct]

I am satisfied with the matrix so far. It calculates well the max values per day and per *ID TOURNEE* for each postal code. However, The values in bold, are not what I want, I'd like to have an additional measure that takes the results of every Max_Heure LIV per day (for example, the non bold values you see for "520") and calculates **their average value** per each *ID TOURNEE*. So, each *ID TOURNEE* will have an average Max_Heure LIV value (not the 13:31, which is the max, not the average).

As a solution, I've tried:

```
AVG = AVERAGEX(Values(filtered_POR050[Label_HEURE LIV]), [Max_Heure LIV])
```

But this gives me a 0 everywhere, what should I do?

Comment: Remove FORMAT from your measures. It converts their results into strings. Instead, just format measures themselves: https://radacad.com/custom-format-fields-and-measures-in-power-bi

Comment: Thank you, this did gave a result but it gives 0 everywhere, so still no solution

Comment: if you want averages by ID TOURNEE, why then you are iterating by Label_HEURE LIV?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was:

```
AVG_Max = 
FORMAT(averagex(
SUMMARIZE(filtered_POR050, filtered_POR050[GroupeCP],filtered_POR050[ID TOURNEE], filtered_POR050[JOUR LIV], "MAX", [Max_Heure LIV]), 
[MAX]), "hh:mm")
```